# How can I obtain all posts published in the last hour from a blog (built with django) with a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

That's my idea but obviously doesn't work....

Thanks

```
def PostUltimaOra(request):
    PostsLastHour = Post.objects.filter(pub_date__time__range=(datetime.time.now, datetime.time(now- 1h)))
    return render(request, 'blog/numeroposts.html', {'PostsLastHour': PostsLastHour})
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite the title to a more compact and descriptive title. Right now this looks more like something that belongs to the question body.

Comment: Sorry. You are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of the 2-tuple is the minimum bound, you thus should swap the elements:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

def PostUltimaOra(request):
    dt = now()
    PostsLastHour = Post.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(dt-timedelta(hours=1), dt))
    return render(request, 'blog/numeroposts.html', {'PostsLastHour': PostsLastHour})
```

If there are no `Post`s after the current timestamp, you can filter with:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

def PostUltimaOra(request):
    dt = now() - timedelta(hours=1)
    PostsLastHour = Post.objects.filter(pub_date__gte=dt)
    return render(request, 'blog/numeroposts.html', {'PostsLastHour': PostsLastHour})
```